# Clone Row (copy records) in Oracle Apex is not working

Tags: javascript, clone, oracle-apex, tabular-form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fn_CloneRow(pThis) {
        $(pThis).parent().parent().clone().appendTo($(pThis).parent().parent().parent());
    }
```

With the use of above code I am able to clone clicked rows in a tabular form to the bottom of the table, but I am unable store them. When I change values of cloned rows, the original row is updated instead of adding a new row when the page is submitted.

Comment: Please also clarify what kind of report it is: I presume it is a wizard generated tabular form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because in cloning the row you also clone the element containing the primary key. 
From the top of my head, do this with the following elements:

- empty the input element containing the PK (you'll need to find out if this is array f01 or any other. Your question does not provide context) or if you use rowid, clean out the input element with name "frowid"
- empty the input element containing the row checksum. This is an input element with name "fcs"
- set the input element containing the record status (name = fcud) to 'C' . It is used to determine what action to perform on it. 'D' is new, 'C' is changed and 'U' is update - I presume. This is not in any documentation though, it is by inspecting the html and javascript you can find this.

You can further improve your code by not doing `parent().parent()...` and instead simply look up the closest tr or table by using `.closest(...)`

```
var newRow = $(pThis).closest('tr').clone();
$('input[name=f01]', newRow).val(""); //input with PK value -- make sure this matches your situation!!!
$('input[name=frowid]', newRow).val(""); //or if the form works with rowid, use this
$('input[name=fcs]', newRow).val(""); //clear the checksum
$('input[name=fcud]', newRow).val("C"); //set the record status
newRow.appendTo($(pThis).closest('table')); //finally, append the row to the table
```

Comment: Thanks a lot TOM for earliest reply. Yes your assumption is correct it is Tabular form. Since i am new to apex, I can understood your explanation but unable to code. Can you suggest with code.

Comment: @Vijayan I added a code sample. You may want to read up a bit on the use of the global arrays in tabular forms (or apex in general) to make sure you understand what happens (by which I mean the f## arrays and how they map to items in the tabular form). I strongly suggest to inspect your generated html, this can help you understand greatly.

Comment: Great TOM. Thanks a lot for your immediate help. I will use it and as u suggested i will inspect the element in browser through HTML..

Comment: Hi Tom, I have done as you said. But i can only clone row but i unable to save. While i submit, the clone row is went off when the page is refreshed.. and after clone row the id of the original and cloned rows are same.. what is the solution??

Comment: That probably is because the ID is not being wiped in the copied element. I can't offer any further insight than advising you to check the html after the copy and see what is in the input item holding the ID. Is the PK held in f01? These things can vary and depend on your setup, so I can only guess when I can't see. Set up an example on apex.oracle.com and I/we could take a look there, or provide your source sql and report attributes screenshot.